# Inserting a node in a linked list C: expected node_t * but argument is of type node_t

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I can not insert a new list into my struct. Can someone please help me? Thanks! :) 
This is my code and error:

Error after compiling:

27:9: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'node_t {aka struct _node_t}' from type 'node_t * {aka struct _node_t *}'

Code:

```
typedef struct _node_t {
    double d;
    struct _node_t *next;
    } node_t;

void print_list (node_t *l) {
    node_t *curr = l;
    printf("[");

    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (l != curr) printf (",");
        printf("%4.1f",curr->d);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    printf("]\n");
}

node_t *insert (node_t *l, double d) {
    node_t *new_node;
    new_node = (node_t *) malloc (sizeof(node_t));

    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("insert: error: no space left\n");
        return l;
    }

    new_node->d = d;
    new_node->next = l;
    return new_node;
}

int main (void) 
{   
    node_t n1;

    print_list(&n1);
    n1=insert(n1,10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `insert` has the return type `node_t *` that is a pointer type.

However in main you are trying to assign the returned pointer to an object of a non-pointer type.

```
node_t n1;
//...
n1=insert(n1,10);
```

Moreover the object `n1` is not initialized.

You need to write in main

```
node_t *n1 = NULL;
print_list( n1 );
n1=insert( n1, 10 );
```

And it seems it is better to exchange the last two statements in main like

```
node_t *n1 = NULL;
n1=insert( n1, 10 );
print_list( n1 );
```